# Counting group invariants using Macdonald conjecture?

Tags: gr.group-theory, weyl-group

It is known from Dyson, Macdonald $et$ $al$ that the constant term asscoiated to the expansion of the following expression

\begin{equation}
\prod_{\alpha \in \Delta} (1-e^{\alpha})^k
\end{equation}

is given by

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i} \left( \begin{array}{ccc} k d_i\\ k \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

where $d_i$ are the fundamental invariants of the Weyl group. I wonder if there is an intuitive way to understand this expression; it only depends on the group and on the value of external parameter $k$. What kind of group invariants it tries to compute, given a sequence of $k$? For example, if $k=1$ then one is counting the product of degree of invariant polynomials; but if $k=2$, what quantity of the group is reflected in the constant term?

Comment: It would help to add a reference to the literature, as well as to define $\Delta$.   Maybe it's also useful to spell out the case where the Weyl group is $S_n$?  (Note too that the product of the $d_i$ is just the group order.)